# Внутреннее перенаправление трафика на ngnix

Tags: битрикс, веб-сервер

Как сделать внутреннее перенаправление трафика на ngnix или апач на папку сайта, отдавая сайт с папки site1 при заходе с поддомена pod.site1 и отдавая сайт с папки site2 при заходе с поддомена pod.site2 без изменения NS в основных доменах

Требуется настроить конфигурацию vps?
Спасибо за подсказки.

Comment: решение добавление поддомена в строку 
server {
    listen 80 ;
  
    server_name  site1  www.site1  poddomen.site1;
...

Answer (score 0):

решение добавление поддомена в строку server_name

```
    server { 
     listen 80 ; 
     server_name site1 www.site1 poddomen.site1; 
...
```